# Object is currently in use elsewhere

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I am using the following code

The following error occurs

Object is currently in use elsewhere.

Please show me the right way

```
 Random rnd = new Random();

        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);


        Parallel.For(0, 1000,
                     i =>
                     pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawEllipse(p, rnd.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width),
                                                              rnd.Next(pictureBox1.Height),
                                                              10, 20)); // error runtime
```

Comment: Presumably the `pictureBox1` object is telling you that it's not threadsafe. (You should also note that the `Random` class isn't threadsafe either.)

Comment: Probably the Random being acceded by multiple threads try replacing rnd.Next with new Random.Next.

Comment: @user629926: You're right that `Random` isn't threadsafe, but it doesn't produce any friendly-ish errors like *"Object is currently in use elsewhere"*; it just breaks!

Comment: @jack: Don't use `Parallel.For`. Use a standard `for` loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1060338/629926 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3327498/629926 and

Answer (score 0):

rnd.Next has side effects, and is not thread-safe.

Try Jon Skeet's [ThreadLocal solution.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx)